# How did Jetty address CERT-2011-003 CVE-2011-4461?

Tags: jetty

I would like to know the code changes done as part of  [CERT-2011-003](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html) and [CVE-2011-4461](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-4461) in Jetty code, and which all files are modified.

Answer (score 0):

These were reported and fixed via [Eclipse RT/Jetty Bug #367638](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367638).

The commits:

1. Git Commit [`#d0b81a185c260ffceecb9d7470b3ddfbfeda4c11`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?id=d0b81a185c260ffceecb9d7470b3ddfbfeda4c11)
2. Git Commit [`#979d6dbbf9416b1a0ad965e2b8a3b11a2d208627`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?id=979d6dbbf9416b1a0ad965e2b8a3b11a2d208627)